# Jquery not working in Chrome Extension when trying to get div text

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a google chrome extension with the following manifest that declare Jquery:

```
"content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js":      ["thirdParty/jquery.min.js","content.js"]
  }],
```

with the content.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").html("JQUERY");
    alert($("#title").html);
});
```

and an html where i run the chrome extension it contain the div

```
<div id="title">test</div>
```

so when i start my page it will change the text of the div from test to JQUERY and then trigger an alert that shows div text that should be JQUERY.

It doesnt display JQUERY but this:

```
function (a){return J(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a&&1===b.nodeType)return b.innerHTML;if("string"==typeof a&&!db.test(a)&&!ib[(bb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){a=a.replace(ab,"<$1>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(n.cleanData(ob(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)}function (a){return J(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a&&1===b.nodeType)return b.innerHTML;if("string"==typeof a&&!db.test(a)&&!ib[(bb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()]){a=a.replace(ab,"<$1>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(n.cleanData(ob(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#title").html("JQUERY");` changes the HTML correctly since you are passing the string `"JQUERY"` to the funtion `html(param)`.

To retrieve the html-code you need to call the same method, this time without any parameters: `alert($("#title").html());`. This way the function figures you dont want to change the behaviour but instead you are wishing to get its current HTML content.

What is actually happening in your case is that you are outputting the code that IS the function `html()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `$("#title").html()` instead of printing the `$("#title").html` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").html("JQUERY");
    alert($("#title").html());
});
```